# create, update and delete JSON object in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to make simple application with reading data from json file, I have **article.json** with this this objects:

```
"articles" : [
   {
      "id": 1,
      "title": "Example 1",
      "likes": 0,
      "unlikes": 0
   },
   {
      "id": 2,
      "title": "Example 2",
      "likes": 0,
      "unlikes": 0
   }
]
```

I didn't find the simplest way to update for example number of likes or to add new object with the following attributes using jquery. Any tips or ideas? Thanks

Comment: do you want to update the json file or just the json object?

Comment: @RahulR.I First I want to update json object and then json file

Comment: Where is that file located? Since you want to use jQuery I assume it’s a browser application, so you either need to provide it upfront (along with your script) or load it dynamically, e.g. from a URL.

Comment: @jotaen the json file is located in the project folder with the html file where I post the json data and I want to change that json file

Comment: You don’t necessarily need jQuery for this then. Do you already know ways to make AJAX requests? jQuery: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/ or generally: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API

Comment: @jotaen i started with jquery i need to finish with that

Comment: Then you could search for how to do AJAX requests with jQuery. With that technique you can fetch JSON from a URL (server) and it gets automatically converted to a JavaScript object that you then can work with.

Answer (score 0):

If you successfully get the result, First you have to convert JSON to JS object, for that you have to use:

```
var globalArticle = null;

$.getJSON("article.json", function(result){
      // you will get result as JS Object
      globalArticle = result;
});
```

Now if you want to add a new article just push it in the returned JS Object but to use it outside of anonymous function you have to create & pass it to a global 
 variable that way I use it above.

```
var newArticle = {id: 10, title: 'new title', likes: 0, unlikes: 0}
globalArticle.push(newArticle)
```

for saving it in the article.js file, you have to pass it to server through ajax and execute the saving script at the server side.